# Rearrange part of JSON based on a value

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON and I wanted to re-arrange based on 'rank' if the type is 'fruit' or 'meat'. And keep the rest of the JSON as it is in the order it appears. The type 'fruit' and 'meat' will have rank, but the type 'vegetable' and 'diary' rank is not a mandatory that it might not have it for some cases.

**Original value:**

```
var results = {"docs":[
  {"type":"fruit","name":"apple","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"carrot","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"grape","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"beef","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"fish","rank": 10.1}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"tamato"}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"chicken","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"eggs"}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"peas","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"orange","rank": 9.1}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"milk","rank": 10},
  {"type":"fruit","name":"banana","rank": 9.8}
]};
```

**Expected value:**

```
var results = {"docs":[
  {"type":"fruit","name":"apple","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"banana","rank": 9.8},
  {"type":"fruit","name":"orange","rank": 9.1}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"grape","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"fish","rank": 10.1}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"chicken","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"beef","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"carrot","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"tamato"}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"eggs"}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"peas","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"milk","rank": 10}
]};
```

Thanks in advance. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs element of your JSON object is an array of JSON objects, so you can use the Array.sort() method to sort your JSON objects (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  The trick is to write a sorting function that sorts your JSON objects the way you want them sorted.

I did this by breaking it down in to two functions, one that sorts by type and one that sorts by rank.

When sorting by types, we want fruit to be sorted to a lower index than meat, and dairy and vegetable sorted to a lower index than fruit or meat.  We can use the indexes of the types array in compareType to help us sort by type.  The index of "fruit" is greater than the index of "meat", and the index of anything that's not in the array ("dairy" and "vegetable") is -1.  A lower index in the types array corresponds to a higher index in the final sorted array.  So if a.type < b.type, we return 1.

When sorting by rank, higher ranks should be sorted to lower inedexes.  The final sort function first compares the object's types, and if the types are equal, then it compares their ranks.

```
var results = {"docs":[
  {"type":"fruit","name":"apple","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"carrot","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"grape","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"beef","rank": 9}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"fish","rank": 10.1}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"tamato"}, 
  {"type":"meat","name":"chicken","rank": 10}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"eggs"}, 
  {"type":"vegetable","name":"peas","rank": 0}, 
  {"type":"fruit","name":"orange","rank": 9.1}, 
  {"type":"diary","name":"milk","rank": 10},
  {"type":"fruit","name":"banana","rank": 9.8}
]};

function compareRank(a, b) {
  if(a.rank < b.rank) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if(a.rank > b.rank) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function compareType(a, b) {
  var types = ["meat", "fruit"];

  if(a.type === b.type) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if(types.indexOf(a.type) < types.indexOf(b.type)) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

var docs = results.docs;
docs.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(compareType(a, b) === 0) {
    return compareRank(a, b);
  }
  else {
    return compareType(a, b);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Works perfect.

Comment: I am getting different results on IE and Chrome? The ordering of the meat and fruit are good, but in Chrome sometimes, its not keeping the ordering of the rest of the results.

Comment: My guess is that the different browsers' JavaScript engines implement the sort algorithm differently.  We're treating vegetable and dairy as equal, so maybe Chrome sometimes rearranges vegetable and dairy items.  If they're equal their order shouldn't matter.  I understand that you would like to preserve the ordering of vegetable and dairy.  I don't know how you would do that.  Maybe you could remove them from the array, then add them back after sorting the rest of the array.